# I have used DarkTheme but Its seems like transparent fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

It's like I have used transparent fragments upon the song list and the background is still white. I have used forceDarkAllowed for Dark theme in the themes files. Here is the code of the Theme file.

[This is the screenshot of the dark theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EDcN.jpg)

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_200</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:ignore="NewApi">true</item>
</style>
<style name="Theme.MyApplication.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

</style>
<style name="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
<style name="Theme.MyApplication.AppBarOverlay">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyApplication.PopupOverlay">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/white</item>
    <item name="background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
</style>

<!-- Change tab text appearance -->
<style name="MyCustomTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/CustomTabWidgetText</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTabWidgetText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

and in the MainActivity I have used  `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);`

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);`
If you wanted a dark theme?

`AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);` would fix it.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote No by mistake it was Yes